# Assigning special character

Tags: r

I have a question concerning assigments of special characters in R such as `%,&,!,?,@,etc.`.

For example create two identical functions

```
`?` <- which
`@` <- which
```

The first one will work, not the second

```
# Example 1
# works
?c(T,F)
# [1] 1
# does not work
@c(T,F)
# Error: unexpected '@' in "@"

# Example 2
set.seed(as.Date("2019-02-04"))
m <- matrix(runif(25),3,3)
m
# works
m<.5?T
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   1   2
# [3,]   2   2
# [4,]   1   3
# does not work
m<.5@T
# Error in 0.5@T : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Can anyone explain why that happens and maybe provide a list of some sort of special characters behaving like `?` ?

Comment: @(c(T,F)) does work when we surround @ by `.

Comment: Yes but that is precisely what I want to know - why does it work without ` for `?` but not for other characters?

Comment: It's just how the R parser works. Those functions are defined with different arity. `?` is a unary function so it can start a line, but `@` is a binary function so it doesn't make sense to be at the beginning of a line. Then `which` expects just one parameter, but when you call it like `.5@T`, you are really calling `@(.5, T)` and that .5 is not logical as the error message states. Basicialy you can't alter the precedence or arity of built-in functions because those are set by the parser. See the `?Syntax` help page for some of these rules

Comment: The [R Language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) may also be useful.